# how to check cell duplicate value and special characters not allowed and blanks cell in java

Tags: java, jsp

I am new for java upload Excel POI API , now i have tried to implement all validation in java code . like .

```
                  boolean isduplicate =true;
    String dupcolumn = myRow.getcell(0).toString();

    while(iterate.hasnext())
    {
     String [] dup  = dupcolumn +dupcolumn .split(";");
    }
                 if(duplicate)
    {
             for(int i=0;i<dup.length;i++)
    {

    for(int j=i+1;j<dup.length;j++)
    {
    if(dup[j]==dup[i])
    {
    System.out.println("Duplicate");
    isduplicate =false;
    }
    }
    }


}
```

In the above i am split method i am getting first column repeated contiguously .because inside while loop. if any one let me know how i can achieve to find duplicate cell value either string or numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` method to compare String, instead of `==`

```
if(dup[j]==dup[i])
```

Comment: i have another code like String dup = ""; while(iterate.hasnext()){ String dupcolumn = myRow.getcell(0);dup.contains(dupcolumn);} in that code contains not working . both which one best approach code .

Answer (score 0):

Put all the values in the hashset. Hashset wont allow duplicate values in it. Count the length of the hashset and the toal row's in the excel file. The difference in these two values gives you the total no. of duplicate cells.

if you want the duplicate values. do this

```
if(hashSet.contains(value)  {
    System.out.println(value):
}
```

This will print the duplicate value